# Delete numpy arrays from memory after loading into tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have 4 numpy arrays `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train`, `y_test` which consume about 5GB of memory. I have loaded these into tensorflow with the following code.

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))
```

`train_dataset` and `test_dataset` together use about 8GB of memory. The problem is that I am running out of memory and I no longer have any use of the numpy arrays. How can I free those variables from memory?

I tried `del <variable_name>` in python, but it seems it deletes only the pointer and does not free the memory.

Setting the variables to `0` also doesn't work.

Here is the code if that could help.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-nv_JRQnC3YBfyoacdufCnB6LRJacPCt?usp=sharing

The dataset is
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/theoviel/rsna-breast-cancer-256-pngs

and, here is the train.csv
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/rsna-breast-cancer-detection/data?select=train.csv

Comment: I am starting to think this is more like a memory leak on the side of numpy. Setting the variables to 0 should have freed the memory. Maybe numpy thinks tensorflow or some other part of the code needs that memory.

Comment: How were `xtrain` etc created?  Are they views of something else?  `xtrain.base` might show this.  I don't know enough of the tensorflow code to test whether it's retaining a reference to the numpy arrays (or the base).

Comment: x_train is numpy array of png files. There are probably better ways to load images into tensorflow, but I could not get it to work for my use case and so ended up converting them into numpy arrays. @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you:

1-> Maybe, it is possible that **tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices** creates a view over the original array, so the memory cannot be deleted. In any, case try to put the this part inside a function like this:

```
def load_data():
  # load your numpy arrays 
  # x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test  
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)), tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))
```

I expect that when function return any temporal variable inside the function scope will be release (including your numpy arrays), but since you mentioned that **del** didn't work, maybe this didn't work either. But hey, Python sometimes acts in mysterious ways.

2-> If the option 1 don't work, try to use memory mapping (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)

Comment: I am not sure if it "creates a view over the original array", I think the memory is being copied. When that specific cell runs, I see the memory usage go up by 7-8 GB. 
But yeah, I will try to refactor the code according to your suggestion

Comment: Tried refactoring according to your suggestion, it did not work.

Comment: And Did you tray with memory mapping?

Comment: Some time ago, I create a simple python script to serialize a huge images dataset (images and labels) using lmdb dataset (I faced the same problem as you :) ). I heavy used this script in my ML project with PyTorch , I don't know if this can be useful for you in TF, if you think so let me know and I can upload the code to my github

Comment: Did not try memory mapping yet, but I think it will work. Will report once I try. At the end of the day, all I want is to load images into tensorflow. Your script could be useful. Let me know once you upload it.

Comment: @berinaniesh sorry for the delay. You can find the script here [https://github.com/otre99/SimplyLMDBForCV] I will prepare some use case as examples

Answer (score 0):

according to official python documents, you can call garbage collector after delete variable. This action clears the memory of unreferenced objects

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Comment: I am guessing this works only for native python memory, tried it, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By my reading of your notebook,

```
train_dataset, test_dataset = load_data()
```

gets 2 tensors, with tensorflow reporting on memory use.

With in `load_data`, all the `png` are loaded into a list, `dataset` (as arrays).  That is then split into train/test  with

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=69)
```

I'm not familiar with `train_test_split` and don't know whether it is returning lists of arrays, or arrays.  That is, I don't know if the following `np.asarray` line is needed or not.  Either way you end up with a copies for all the `png` arrays in `dataset` (selection is random, not by slice).

Then you make `tensors` from those arrays, and return those.

Since `dataset` and `train/test` arrays are local to `load_data`, they will be deleted, and their space freed up.  For smallish arrays, `numpy` can put the freed up memory in a 'freememory' for later reuse, but these are probably large enough that the space is returned to the OS.  Before exiting the function, memory use could be quite high, roughly 3x the size of `dataset` (`dataset` plus the split copies, plus the tensors).

While I see a `Allocation of 2868117504 exceeds 10% of free system memory.` warning, I don't see a memory error.  The error in the notebook display is not a memory one.

Comment: `train_test_split` returns the same type as that of input. The input were lists and so the outputs are also lists. 
Since `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train`, `y_test` were lists of numpy arrays, giving them as input to tensorflow crashes tensorflow. So, `np.asarray` was necessary.

Comment: "`numpy` can put the freed up memory in a 'freememory' for later reuse". Maybe this is the case. Because deleting the variables or setting them to 0 doesn't free the memory to the OS. Maybe I can test it by using more memory in numpy and testing if memory usage goes up.

Comment: There are no memory errors with the notebook. It is just that I don't see memory released to the OS on my task manager.